# Google Drive iOS SDK Shared Folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I have an iOS app that loads PDF's for viewing.  I want to allow the app to get the PDF's from a shared folder in google drive that is shared by some main admin account.

I have created a google drive project and set up OAuth for my app and am able to successfully list files using various queries with GTLQueryDrive.

The issue I am facing is related to the auth scope.

Lets say the google account hosting the files contains a shared folder:  PDFAppFiles.  We share this folder with 20 people.

Is there a way in my iOS app to request the auth scope for just that folder?  I don't see this option listed:  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/scopes

Or, should I be approaching this problem a different way?

Answer (score 0):

As the scopes page suggest, it authorizes your app to do what the requested scope is. This is a bit different from asking or setting permissions to a file or folder.

My recommended approach for the problem is to set permissions for every folder you want to control. The [Share Files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/manage-sharing) page of the Drive documentation details how you can do it.